# No Longer Able to Modify Directory on Amazon S3, Why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, permissions, web-hosting

So today I thought to start off my website as just a static website using Amazon S3 as it's extremely cheap, after figuring it out, redirecting my domain and uploading my index I can no longer add ANYTHING, can't create another folder, upload the rest of my files via web management console, NOTHING, and I must have changed a setting at some point cause I had no problem creating the css folder and such.

I get an error with really no explanation saying:

> Error: Failed to create Folder with name 'images'

or

When uploads fail it's under a category named 'Forbidden'

I'm pretty frustrated at this point after the difficulties I had with bucket permissions and such.

Any ideas on where to look?

**EDIT:** Tried creating a new bucket and received the following error:

> Bucket btbtestrun created successfully. Error setting properties and permissions on the bucket.

Although I am able to upload images to the new bucket.

[Screenshot of bucket Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VutBK.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like a permission issue. I would suggest starting by trying to create a new Amazon S3 bucket and seeing whether you can upload files to it. If this is not possible, then you know it is a general issue affecting your use of Amazon S3 that is not related to a specific bucket. Check the IAM permissions associated with the set of credentials you are using to call AWS. Feel free to edit your question to provide the result of these tests, and also include details of _how_ you are calling AWS — is it via the web management console, or via the AWS CLI?

Comment: Thanks for helping add more detail that may identify the problem. *Updated

Comment: You'll need to check what Amazon S3 permissions have been granted to _you_ (that is, the IAM User that you are using). If anything is acting strangely on one particular bucket, then you'll also need to check the Bucket Policy that is assigned to the bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was infact a permissions issue, I had my permissions to write objects unchecked, a change I must've accidentally made at some point

John Rotensein definitely helped me come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error message shows up due to the "Default Encryption" bucket property as well. e.g.
You have the Default Encryption for the bucket data to be AES-256 and you are trying to create a folder without any server-side encryption. AWS console will show you this same type of error message.